# Simple code and Error happens on Form Close

Tags: forms, delphi

Tell me, where is a problem:

The First Form:

```
procedure TForm2.N6Click(Sender: TObject);
var About:TAbout;
begin
 About:=TAbout.Create(Application);
 try
   About.ShowModal;
 finally
   About.Free;
 end;
end;
```

The Second Form:

```
procedure TAbout.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 About.Close;
end;
```

on About.Close I got Error: EAccessViolation. I do not do anything else with form About, a code of About is empty, just button click.

Comment: If I click X in the right corner (close) - all is OK!!!

Answer (score 11):

Although Doug is right, the simplest solution is to only make the change

```
procedure TAbout.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Close;
end;
```

which anyway is the 'right' version of the procedure. If you click the `Button1` of the current `TAbout` form (that is, `Self`), you naturally wish to close the current `TAbout` form (that is `Self`). And `Close` is short-hand for `Self.Close` when inside the `TAbout` class.

`TAbout` is a *class* of a form. You can create any number of *instances*, so called *objects*, of this class. Normally there is a global `About` variable in your project, and this object is automatically created when your application starts. To show this, you only need to do

```
procedure TForm2.N6Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  About.ShowModal;
end;
```

Another approach, is to disable the auto-creation of the `About` form (Project/Options), and then create a new instance every time you need one. Then you do

```
procedure TForm2.N6Click(Sender: TObject);
var About:TAbout;
begin
  About := TAbout.Create(nil);
  try
    About.ShowModal;
  finally
    About.Free;
  end;
end;
```

In *any* case, you want

```
procedure TAbout.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Close; // same thing as Self.Close;
end;
```

Answer (score 7):

When you declared the `About` variable in the TForm2.N6Click method, you do not use the global About global variable.

But in the About form, when you try to call `Close` on `About` variable you use the global variable, which in this case remains uninitialized.

Try removing the local `About` declaration, it should work.

Comment: Yes, Doug got the reason for the error correct. And yes, the suggested work-around works, but it isn't really right. You are shooting yourself in your foot by creating and freeing a `TAbout` object using the global variable in a local procedure. See my answer.